# William James, Biography

Tags: history-of-philosophy, william-james

I am writing a report on William James, and I need the age that James started reading philosophy **for the first time**. Can anyone help?

Comment: coincidentally, a video of a talk by Alan Wallace, admiring and praising William James, has been recently posted to reddit's philosophy channel: https://www.reddit.com/r/philosophy/comments/3jp9w6/toward_the_first_revolution_in_the_mind_sciences/

Answer (score 1):

Given that [James](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_James) wrote that:

> I originally studied medicine in order to be a physiologist; but I drifted into physchology and philosophy through a kind of fatality; I never had any kind of philosophic instruction, the first lecture on psychology I heard was the first I gave. [1]

This is probably something of an exaggeration given that his father was a noted Swedenbergonian theologian, and was well connected to the intellectual and literary elites; it's likely his philosophical orientation was fixed in an unconscious kind of way through his families milieu and circle.

[1] The thought and character of William James, Vol 1 - Ralph Perry